# How do I convert a list to a string but display elements of a CSV file?

Tags: python, string, list, csv

I need to display this :4 choices made so far = ['1', '2', '8', '6'] and cost = £  20.8

In this format:

Dish No   course         dish                          price          suitable for vegetarians

0         starter        Pan-fried Tiger Prawns        4.5            yes

I aslo need to try and include at the end how many dishes are not suitable for vegetarians

---

Here is my attempt:

```
spent = 0
order = []
menu = [
    ['course', 'dish', 'price', 'suitable for vegetarians'],
    ['starter', 'Liver Pate and Toast', '3.5', 'no'],
    ['main course', 'Beef Wellington', '10.95', 'no'],
    ['main course', 'Honey Glazed Duck Breast', '9.5', 'no'],
    ['dessert', 'Tiramisu', '3.5', 'yes'],
    ['dessert', 'Rhubarb Crumble', '3.9', 'yes']
]

#Menu imported into python, no need to leave file open
while True:
    dishes = -1

    for dish in menu:
        if dishes == -1:
                print ("Dish No".ljust(10), end="")
        else:
                print(str(dishes).ljust(10), end="")

        print(dish[0].ljust(15), end="")
        print(dish[1].ljust(30), end="")
        print(dish[2].ljust(15), end="")
        print(dish[3], end="\n\n")
        dishes += 1

    reply = input("Please choose your first item: ")
    if reply.upper () == "Q":
        break

    print()
    spent = spent + float(menu[int(reply)+1][2])
    order = order + [reply]
    print(len(order), "choices made so far =", order, "and cost = £ ", spent)
    print()
    print ("Please choose an item from the menu (0-9 or press Q to end): ")
    print()
    print ((order)dish[0,1,2,3]) #Displays order as text and not list
```

The CSV file has this inside it:

course  dish    price   suitable for vegetarians
starter Pan-fried Tiger Prawns  4.5 yes
starter Goat's Cheese on Bruschetta 3.9 yes
starter Liver Pate and Toast    3.5 no
main course Beef Wellington 10.95   no
main course Vegetarian Filo Roulade 7.5 yes
main course Poached Salmon With Dill    11.5    no
main course Honey Glazed Duck Breast    9.5 no
dessert Tiramisu    3.5 yes
dessert Deep Dish Apple Pie 3.9 yes
dessert Rhubarb Crumble 3.9 yes

Comment: Someone did mention in a separate post to look at str.join but I have no idea how to use it

Comment: Great! Now, there's another error from the last line (`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`). See if you can fix that to what you wanted to do. Then I might be able to run it :).

Comment: That last line can be deleted, that is the bit I am stuck on. I am trying to get the order that has been selected to print as a text list and not integer.

The last line is me experementing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider

```
    reply = input("Please choose your first item: ")
    if reply.upper () == "Q":
        break
```

You want it as an integer, so do that first:

```
    reply = int(reply)
```

Add to `spent` and to `order`:

```
    print()
    spent += float(menu[reply+1][2])
    order.append(reply)
```

Print some menu stuff as before:

```
    print(len(order), "choices made so far =", order, "and cost = £ ", spent)
    print()
    print ("Please choose an item from the menu (0-9 or press Q to end): ")
    print()
```

You can print the item chosen with `menu[reply+1][1]`:

```
    print("You ordered", menu[reply+1][1], "bringing your total to", spent)
    print()
```

Comment: That pretty much did it. Got a completely separate error due to try and except but it works now for the most part. Thanks for the help and being so patient